# How would I create a dynamic find_by method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I trying to create a dynamic find_by method in my rails 3 application. What I'm trying to do follows:

```
My_dynamic_find(Model, {attribute_hash})
```

The method would work as follows on a User model:

```
My_dynamic_find(User, {:name => "Bill", :gender => "male", :weight => 200)
```

the method would then execute the following:

```
User.find_by_name_and_gender_and_weight("Bill","male",200)
```

Is this possible and is this an example of meta-programming.

Comment: Do you mean like `User.where(:name => 'Bill', :gender => 'male', :weight => 200)`? It is not metaprogramming.

Comment: Wow, I was so focused on how to figure it out using Find_by that I totally forgot about where.  Thanks. If you want to make it an answer its all yours.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
User.where( :name => 'Bill', :gender => 'male', :weight => 200 )
```

It isn't metaprogramming. Metaprogramming is when your program is dynamically creating other parts of the program. :)